# Meteor - Error: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

When I try to load [my site](http://travelmore.meteor.com/), I keep getting an error but when I click around (or refresh it), it will load. I installed Kadira and my hunch is that it has to do with this error that I keep getting. I am brand new to Meteor so any help on how to solve this issue or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined
    at http://telescope69-31112.onmodulus.net/098c59227b0946cb6e4d16eb639bd6614d1f3aa0.js:178:2385
    at HTMLDocument.o (http://telescope69-31112.onmodulus.net/098c59227b0946cb6e4d16eb639bd6614d1f3aa0.js:3:4858)
```

The console also shows this sometimes. When i click around, eventually it will load and this goes away.

```
You called Router.path for a route named posts_top but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it? e33d8ba9590e57dfcfd2efb1dbbbfae4459966a7.js:109
You called Router.path for a route named posts_new but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it? e33d8ba9590e57dfcfd2efb1dbbbfae4459966a7.js:109
You called Router.path for a route named posts_best but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it? e33d8ba9590e57dfcfd2efb1dbbbfae4459966a7.js:109
You called Router.path for a route named posts_digest but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it? e33d8ba9590e57dfcfd2efb1dbbbfae4459966a7.js:109
You called Router.path for a route named postsDaily but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it? e33d8ba9590e57dfcfd2efb1dbbbfae4459966a7.js:109
You called Router.path for a route named posts_top but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it? e33d8ba9590e57dfcfd2efb1dbbbfae4459966a7.js:109
You called Router.path for a route named posts_new but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it? e33d8ba9590e57dfcfd2efb1dbbbfae4459966a7.js:109
You called Router.path for a route named posts_best but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it? e33d8ba9590e57dfcfd2efb1dbbbfae4459966a7.js:109
You called Router.path for a route named posts_digest but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it? e33d8ba9590e57dfcfd2efb1dbbbfae4459966a7.js:109
You called Router.path for a route named postsDaily but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it? e33d8ba9590e57dfcfd2efb1dbbbfae4459966a7.js:109
```

Comment: Can you show your codes? The helpers part and the template part

Comment: It is all one line and really hard to read. is there a better way to share it?

Comment: You should share it here, with a link to pastebin. But the primary place to share all info pertaining to the question is in the question body here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by "HTMLDocument.o", looks like your app is running in production.

Try running it locally in debug mode (`meteor run`) and see what errors you get in the browser console.

Comment: Try to deploy by `meteor --debug yoursite.meteor.com`. Then it's easier for us to help you